# SyntaxError: function statement requires a name - jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What is wrong with my `function name`?

When I implement the following, I get a `SyntaxError: function statement requires a name` warning in my console. I have included jQuery earlier in the code, so it's not that.

```
function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $(':input').blur(function () {
            if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'completed', $(this).attr('name')]);
            } 
            else {
                _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Modals', 'skipped', $(this).attr('name')]);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', '*****']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', '*****']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview'], ['_trackPageLoadTime']);

(function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing a bracket in line one, missing '('